# combine multiple bash scripts

Tags: bash, unix, merge

I am working with RNAseq data and I am doing the mapping in unix.Si I have several individual bash scripts, which everyone using as input the output of the previous one. Now I want to merge them all together and run one script at once.
I am pretty new in Unix environment and I don't know how to this, i guess it's not just copy pasting , right

PS. first thing i supposed I have to change variable f to another,let's say z

first script :

```
for f in `ls ../reads/*.fastq.gz | sed 's/_[12].fastq.gz//g' `

do

hisat2 -x ../genome -1 ${f}_01.fastq.gz -2 ${f}_02.fastq.gz > ${f}.mapped.sam

done
```

second script :

```
for f in `ls  *.mapped.sam|sed 's/.mapped.sam//g' `

do

samtools view -b ${f} > ${f}.mapped.bam

done
```

Comment: copy pasting will work

Comment: you can also create a script that will run those two : script 3 : `sh script1.sh && sh script2.sh`

Comment: And the first person to suggest copy'n'paste gets evicted from their computer science class for … oh, this is not allowed to be NSFW.

Comment: When writing shell scripts, you're often best off taking the file names to be processed as arguments, rather than trying to parse the output of `ls` or working with other fixed names.  `for file in "$@"; do …; done` and then using `bash script.sh *.mapped.sam` is generally better (and a lot more flexible) than using a version with `ls *.mapped.sam` in it.

Comment: Thank you both I will try and see

Answer (score 1):

With a single loop and `bash`'s variable substitution:

```
for f in `ls ../reads/*.fastq.gz`
do
    f="${f/_[12].fastq.gz/}"
    hisat2 -x ../genome -1 ${f}_01.fastq.gz -2 ${f}_02.fastq.gz | samtools view - -b -o ${f}.mapped.bam
done
```

Related note: *"Samtools is designed to work on a stream. It regards an input file `-` as the standard input (stdin)"*

Comment: It's curious that for each file in `../reads/` that matches `xyz_[12].fastq.gz`, there are two other files in the directory `xyz_01.fastq.gz` and `xyz_02.fastq.gz` — but those names also match `*.fastq.gz`.  This is a problem in the original first script — not unique to your solution which is perfectly reasonable.  If the intermediate `xyz.mapped.sam` file is wanted for some reason, you can add `| tee ${f}.mapped.sam` before the pipe in your solution.